# Calculating distances on grid

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, grid, distance

I have a 10 x 10 grid of cells (as a numpy array).  I also have a list of 3 points on that grid.  For each cell on the grid, I need to find the closest of the three points.  I can do this in series of nested loops in python (2.7) which works but is slow (especially if I upscale to larger grids) but I suspect there is a faster way.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Share sample input, output and your attempt with the for-loop code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I know of to calculate the distance between two points on a plane is using the Pythagorean theorem.

That is, picture a right angle triangle where the hypotenuse goes between the two points and the base of the triangle is parallel to the x axis and the height is parallel to the y axis. We then know that the distance (represented by the length of the hypotenuse) h adheres to the following: h^2 = a^2 + b^2, where a and b are the lengths of the two remaining sides of the triangle.

It's hard to give any other help without seeing your code. Have you tried something similar yet? You need to specify your question more if you want more specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

**If we assume that you know the point coord**, then you can calculate the distance between a cell and the point using the distance formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance

So for example, let's say that your cell correspond to 'x' and your 3 points correspond to y1, y2 and y3. You can simply get the distance between x - y1, x - y2 and x - y3 and then compare the three distances.

**If we assume that you do not know the point coord**, then you first have to find the point coord. You can find the point coord by scanning your grid and cheecking if a cell correspond to a point coord. When you found all your point, you can find the closest distance using the formula distance.

Answer (score 0):

There is function in `scipi` called `euclidean` that will calculate the distances between points, if you want to loop through them.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 1, 1])
b = np.array([2, 2, 2])
dist = euclidean(a, b)
```

But I think for large data sets you would be better of using `scipi`'s [k-d tree](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) to preform the search.